# Migrate application in Meteor 1.4

Tags: meteor

I am trying to migrate my application in Meteor 1.4 and currently it is on meteor 1.2 so I should go as defined in below link or change my complete code as per meteor doc.

http://info.meteor.com/blog/how-to-update-enterprise-meteor-application-to-1.4

Comment: As mentioned in the link, one should evaluate the upgrade on a branch instead of master. The question in general is too broad to answer. Based on 'error messages' that you get on trying , a solution may be proposed.

Comment: If you are upgrading from 1.2 to 1.4, I would suggest to create a new code branch, follow the upgrade path to 1.3, make sure it's working, then follow the upgrade path to 1.4.  The worst thing, IMHO, would be to try to just directly, as you would then not be aware of why a certain thing isn't working.  Is it because of a change to support 1.3 or 1.4?